# While loop is repeating only the first row multiple times

Tags: php

I am trying to output all the rows of  the result of a database query but my while loop keeps repeating only the first row multiple times. It repeats only the first row the total number of times of expected outcome. Please I need help.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM review WHERE lid = '".$_GET['id']."'";
$result = $conn -> query($sql);
$row = $result -> fetch_assoc();

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
    echo "<div class='no-comment'>No Comments found!</div>
    <button class='btn btn-default btn-lg center-block' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#Review'>Review Lecturer Now!</button>
    ";
}else{
    while($result -> fetch_assoc()){
        echo"
            <div class='comment'>
                <div class='reviewer-name'>".$row['rid']."<span class='review-date'>".$row['reviewDate']."</span><hr>
                <p>".$row['review']."</p></div>
            </div>
            ";
    }
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: You're using both the object-oriented interface and the legacy procedural one here for no apparent reason. Stick to the object-oriented interface to avoid confusion and mistakes caused by confusing it with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface.

Comment: Because `$row` is not in while and it's a static array using only first row. You need to do `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
while($result -> fetch_assoc()){
```

To

```
while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
```

Also delete the first `$row = ...` from line 3.

Comment: This solved my issue. I am glad I posted this here. Such a little oversight caused me so much trouble for hours. Thank you everyone